# how to destroy a process generated from a process builder in java

Tags: java, terminal, processbuilder, destroy

I have a `processbuilder` that runs a `.sh script`. it opens a terminal. I want to destroy this terminal later. I tried `process.destroy()` but it did not do the job.

**Code:**

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", "-e", "/home/omar/ros_ws/./baxter2.sh").start();  
try {  
    Thread.sleep(10000); // wait for one second  
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {   
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();  
} 
p.destroy();
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could have the script kill itself once its business has finished?  This is the normal workflow I believe.

Comment: I need to keep this script running all the time except for specific cases. So the general case is that the script is running and stops only in few conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
try  

{

Process[] proc = new Process[2];

proc[0] = new ProcessBuilder("calc.exe").start();

proc[1] = new ProcessBuilder("notepad.exe").start();


try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
}

proc[0].destroy();
proc[1].destroy();
```

}

```
catch (IOException ioe)
 { 
ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```